# How to use a device node that has been disabled in the kernel device tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I'm new to the concepts of kernel and device trees. I have a samsung artik module that runs fedora 24. I need to test one of it's I2S peripherals (it has 3 I2S peripherals). The default I2S is driving the main audio jack and is working fine. I have to test the secondary I2S that is available on a set of gpio pins and we have managed to connect it to an AMP board (TAS5731 EVM of texas instruments) via wires. Now the problem is that the amp board is not detected as an audio device. On further investigation I found out that the I2S peripheral is 'disabled' by default in the device tree. Here is the relevant portions of the device tree:

```
    i2s@c0056000 {
    reg = <0xc0056000 0x1000>;
        frame-bit = <0x20>;
        dmas = <0x3b 0xe 0x3b 0xf>;
        pinctrl-0 = <0x3f>;
        compatible = "nexell,nexell-i2s";
        clock-names = "i2s1";
        reset-names = "i2s-reset";
        mclk-in = <0x0>;
        master-mode = <0x1>;
        clocks = <0x3e>;
        pre-supply-mclk = <0x1>;
        resets = <0x10 0x18>;
        sample-rate = <0xbb80>;
        status = "**disabled**";
        dma-names = "tx", "rx";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        trans-mode = <0x0>;
    };
```

.
.
.

```
    i2s1 {
    nexell,pin-function = <0x3>;
            phandle = <0x3f>;
            nexell,pin-pull = <0x0>;
            nexell,pins = "gpioa-28", "gpioa-30", "gpiob-0", "gpiob-6", "gpiob-9";
            nexell,pin-strength = <0x0>;
            linux,phandle = <0x3f>;
        };
```

My question is, can I enable the peripheral without having to compile the kernel again, that is, from within the running kernel? If not, what are the alternate ways to get it running? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In theory you do not have recompile the entire kernel, but at least recompile the Device Tree (using `dtc`), and you'll need a driver for the slave device.  But that is not the complete answer.  Typically all nonessential peripherals are disabled in the base .dtsi for the SoC.  You can only use and enable the peripherals that do not have conflicting resources, e.g. pins.  IOW you have to verify that the pins required by this second I2C controller are not in use for other functionality